# Unit testing class methods with private setters

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to unit testing and struggling with a simple use case here.
I have setters declared as private(do not want anyone to setup those variables except Spring)

```
private setX(T x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

While writing unit tests I when I want to set value for those variables, I cannot. A quick workaround would be to have public setters but that wouldn't look nice. I am using Mockito as mocking framework and Junit for unit testing.

All help appreciated.

EDIT:

```
Class A {
    private Clazz clazz;
    //to be used only by spring
    private setClazz(Clazz clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them protected or package-private, and put the test in the same package as the class 
under test.

Or use reflection to call the setter, as Spring does.

Or use Mockito's `InjectMocks` annotation, which will inject a mock dependency by calling the setter using reflection for you.

Comment: Any comments on this:http://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Comment: I agree with one of the commenters: what he's actually advocating against is the use of field and setter injection, because constructor injection makes dependencies clearer. Philosophically, I agree with him. Pragmatically, I disagree, because having a constructor initializing fields is boilerplate code, and if you're serious about TDD, you should update the test at the same time you're updating the bean, so you should never be surprised by a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Don't *directly* unit test private members.

(There's a lot of debate on this throughout the internet.)

Unit tests don't necessarily test the *properties* and *methods* in the code, they test the *functionality* of the code.  Specifically, the outward-facing business functionality that the objects expose.  So when you're faced with a private member that needs to be tested, one of two things is true:

1. The business functionality can, depending on state, invoke that private functionality.  Therefore if the current unit tests do not invoke that functionality as part of the code coverage then those tests are not exhaustive and there exists a state which isn't being tested.  Create a test which arranges that state before invoking the public-facing functionality in order to indirectly test that private member.
2. The tests are exhaustive and the business functionality doesn't actually invoke that private member under any known conditions.  In which case that private member can simply be removed from the code.

The principles of object oriented design apply to unit tests just as they do to any other code.  Encapsulation is still encapsulation.  If the unit tests forcibly *break* that encapsulation then they quickly become tightly coupled to the code being tested, which makes them considerably more brittle.

Consider the "refactor" step of the [red/green/refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) cycle.  If a test is tightly coupled to the private internals of the component being tested, then refactoring that component would require changing the tests.  Not just *refactoring* those tests, but *changing* the logic they're testing.  Which breaks that TDD cycle.

Expand that into a larger system of code and the tests become a *hindrance* to refactoring that code, when they should be an *asset* to refactoring that code.  If the tests only validate the resulting outward-facing functionality, the internals of the code can be refactored easily and the tests used to validate the refactoring efforts.

Comment: I am not testing the private method. I am trying to set the value of private variable(which has a private setter as well) to test other pubic functions.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: What functionality *does* set that private member?  What state results in that private member having been set?  I would suggest examining that more deeply.  The goal to avoid tight coupling still remains.  Perhaps the blocking issue here isn't that the test can't arrange the necessary starting state, but that the object(s) need(s) to be changed in order to more explicitly allow that state to be reached.  (I can't say for certain without knowing more about the object(s) in question.)  A dependency that can be injected by the test, perhaps?